# Classifying and formatting mixed data from a webpage using bs4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect information from a webpage listing various bankcard privileges, and parse the data in json. I am able to extract basic fields such as validity dates and names with bs4 and regex quite simply. However, there is a field which I am trying to extract that contains mixed information, including a wide variety of formats and different tags, with tables, simple paragraphs, headers, subheaders and more.

For example, the data on the page could be formatted as such:

```
<h3>
    Promotion Details
</h3>
<p>
    <span style="text-decoration: underline;">
        <strong>
            Text
        </strong>
    </span>
</p>
<p>
    Text
</p>
<p>
    Text
</p>
```

or like such:

```
<h3>
    Text
</h3>
<p>
    Moretext
</p>
```

or even in `<ul>` and `<li>` tags:

```
<h3>
    Promotion Details
</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Text
            <br/>
            Text:
            <strong>
            Promocode
            </strong>
        </li>
        <li>
            Text
            <br/>
            Text:
            <strong>
            Promocode
            </strong>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

or an amalgamation of tags as in:

```
<h3>
    Event Details
</h3>
    <div class="float-fix">
        <table border="0" width="60%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
                        <strong>
                            <span style="font-size: 13px;">
                                Text
                            </span>
                        </strong>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 5px; width: 80%;">
                        <span style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 13px;">
                            Text
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 20%;">
                        <strong>
                            <span style="font-size: 13px;">
                                Text
                            </span>
                        </strong>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 5px; width: 80%;">
                        <span style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 13px;">
                            Text
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<h3>
    Promotion Details
</h3>
<p>
    <span style="text-decoration: underline;">
        Text
    </span>
</p>
<p>
    Text
</p>
<p>
    Text:
    <strong>
        Promocode
    </strong>
</p>
```

Of course I could go about making a script that classifies the data into different formats, and returns the information neatly, but I want to know whether there are any resources available that could help me simplify this process a little, maybe a python module or a library.

If such a resource is unavailable, or would not be an efficient way of approaching this task, what would be the next best alternative?

Comment: use selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I do indeed understand how to locate tags and extract information such as text from them, but I want to know what would be the best way to classify such mixed data and parse it as a neatly formatted json object.